# Visual/Operator-pending autocommand?

Tags: visual-mode, line-numbers, operator-pending-mode

Last week, I turned off `'number'` and have been using only `'relativenumber'`, plus a line/column count in my status line. I don't really look at line numbers that much.

But now I've had a radical idea.

I'd like to turn off numbering completely, and only turn it (`'relativenumber'`) back on

- in visual mode, so I can jump around quickly
- on the ex command-line, so I can build ranges
- in operator-pending mode, so I can provide motions like `3j`

I can handle the command-line stuff with `CmdlineEnter` and `CmdwinEnter` (and corresponding exits).

Visual mode doesn't seem to have a `VisualEnter` event (unlike Insert mode), so I would *probably* have to map `v`, `V`, and `<C-v>` in normal mode (also `gv`...).

But I don't want to remap every operator—it's simply not practical.

Is there a way to detect operator-pending mode, trigger some commands, and either resume mode, or use `feedkeys()` to re-trigger it? Or is this attempt ill-fated?

Answer (score 3):

It's a hack, but you could try this:

```
let [s:last_mode, s:last_state] = ['n', '']
let s:waiting_time = 10
call timer_start(s:waiting_time, {-> s:fire_missing_events()}, {'repeat': -1})

fu! s:fire_missing_events() abort
    if reg_executing() isnot# '' | return | endif
    let [mode, state] = [mode(), state()]
    if s:last_mode is# 'n'
    \ && index(['v', 'V', "\<c-v>"], mode) != -1
    \ && exists('#User#VisualEnter')
        do <nomodeline> User VisualEnter
    elseif s:last_mode isnot# 'n'
    \ && mode is# 'n'
    \ && exists('#User#NormalEnter')
        do <nomodeline> User NormalEnter
    elseif s:last_state !~# 'o'
    \ && state =~# 'o'
    \ && exists('#User#OperatorPendingEnter')
        do <nomodeline> User OperatorPendingEnter
    elseif s:last_state =~# 'o'
    \ && state !~# 'o'
    \ && exists('#User#OperatorPendingLeave')
        do <nomodeline> User OperatorPendingLeave
    endif
    let [s:last_mode, s:last_state] = [mode, state]
endfu

augroup set_rnu
    au!
    au User OperatorPendingEnter,VisualEnter setl rnu | redraw
    au User OperatorPendingLeave,NormalEnter setl nornu
    au CmdlineEnter : if state() !~# 'm' | setl rnu | redraw | endif
augroup END
```

It requires the patch [`8.1.2047`](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2047) to be able to invoke the `state()` function.

---

I briefly tested the code by writing it in `/tmp/vimrc`, and then running:

```
$ vim -Nu /tmp/vimrc +'norm! 14G' <(curl -Ls https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/tools/UTF-8-demo.txt)
```

It seemed to do what you want:

[image]

But I don't know how reliable it is.

---

If you notice a too big impact on Vim's performance, try to increase the value of `s:waiting_time`

---

For more information, see:

```
:h User
:h reg_executing(
:h mode(
:h state(
:h exists(
:h timer_start(
:h :do
```

Comment: This was illustrative, to say the least. But there are weird interactions with `'timeout'`, `'timeoutlen'`, and mappings. For normal operators (`d`, etc.), with timeout on, `timeoutlen=100` gives something similar to your gif. For mappings, their now impossible to complete (they timeout)! Increasing timeoutlen delays the relnums showing up (which may be desirable, who knows). Thanks for the effort; I'll wait to see if anyone comes up with something better, but while this answers the question, it's probably not going to work long-term for me. Thanks!

Comment: Very cool, learned a lot.